# send and receive SMS using GO langage and an USB GSM modem

Tags: go, sms, sms-gateway

i have to develop a SMS gateway that receive and send SMS  throughout a USB Modem and that must  be done with GO language

hope that you can help

Comment: If you want to hire one of us to do it for you, cool, but we're not here to do your paid job for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rough outline

1. Use [goserial](https://code.google.com/p/goserial/) to speak [AT commands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set) to the GSM modem which will appear as a serial device
2. [Send SMS](http://www.diafaan.com/sms-tutorials/gsm-modem-tutorial/at-cmgs-text-mode/)
3. [Receive SMS](http://www.developershome.com/sms/readSmsByAtCommands.asp)
4. Profit!